# Flutter Android 13 splash screen doesn't look right

Tags: android, flutter, splash-screen, android-12, android-13

I've been trying to add a splashscreen to my app, but every configuration that I've tried doesn't produce a nice result.

[image]

This was the last and simplest attempt that I've tried.
I'm testing in on a Samsung Galaxy S21 FE running android 13. I've also tested it with the Android Studio emulator on a Pixel 6 running Android 13 with the same result. My test with a Nexus 5X emulator running Android 11 doesn't have the two size image problem.
I'm using `flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.18`to generate the splash screen.
This is my flutter_native_splash.yaml config:

```yaml
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#eeeeee"
  image: assets/launcher/launcher.png

  android_12:
    image: assets/launcher/launcher_android_12.png
    color: "#eeeeee"

  web: false
```

And these are the two images.

launcher_android_12.png

[image]

launcher.png

[image]

I've tried using both of the images on the general and android_12 config but neither of them generates a better result.
I'd expect to see a continuous splash screen instead of a large image followed by a smaller one.

Comment: you can try adjusting the configuration for the resize_mode property to control how the image is scaled or resized to fit the screen

Comment: @angwrk where would that attribute go?
I don't see it on `flutter_native_splash ` documentation

Comment: for example it may help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ME8Czqc-Oc

Comment: @angwrk the video that you pointed at was made 2 years ago and doesn't have the android_12 config. My problem is with Android 12 and 13 (with Android 11 the splash screen looks fine)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somehow I managed to fix it.

I followed this instruction [Deprecated Splash Screen API Migration](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/android/splash-screen-migration) on flutter's docs.

In my case I had to simply remove this in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
```